# Computed property inside of a computed property

Tags: ios, swift

I have a computed property called count. I was going use this to get the count of two different arrays inside of a singleton; however, when I try to call the function, I'm not allowed to select the computed properties inside of the property. If this isn't allowed in Swift then I will just create a new function to handle the same thing. Just thought it would be much simpler to call ".count"

The setup for the computed property:

```
private var completeTasks: [Task] = []
private var incompleteTasks: [Task] = []

public var count: Int {
    var complete: Int {
        get {
        return completeTasks.count
        }
    }
    var incomplete: Int {
        get {
        return incompleteTasks.count
        }
    }
}
```

[and when I try to call the property:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOAJu.png)

Comment: This would work fine if the array I was trying to access wasn't private.

Comment: well, I was thinking about it but I'm not even sure what you want to achieve here...

Comment: I want to be able to retrieve the count of either completeTasks or incompleteTasks by only having to call the count variable.

Comment: What you need is to return a tuple in your computed property

Comment: like: `var count: (complete: Int, incomplete: Int) { return (completeTasks.count, incompleteTasks.count) }`...?

Comment: @holex yes that's what he can accomplish what he wants

Comment: I can see how that would work! Thanks, I'll retrieve it as a tuple.